# Best way to store data (single object) in Web API project without database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My project group and I are to develop a generic workflow system, and have decided to implement a single Node (a task in the workflow) as a C# Visual Studio Web API project (Using the ASP.NET MVC structure).

In the process of implementing a Node's logic, we've come across the trouble of how to store data in our Node. Our Node specifically consists of a few lists of Uri's leading to other Nodes as well as some status/state boolean values. These values are currently stored in a regular class but with all the values as **internal static fields**.

We're wondering if there's a better way to do this? Particularly, as we'd like to later apply a locking-mechanism, it'd be prefereable to have an object that we can interact with, however we are unsure of how we can access this "common" object in various Controllers - or rather in a single controller, which takes on the HTTP requests that we receive for ou Node.

Is there a way to make the Controller class use a modified constructor which takes this object? And if so, the next step: Where can we provide that the Controller will receive the object in this constructor? There appears to be no code which instantiates Web API controllers.

Accessing static fiels in some class seems to do the trick, data-wise, but it forces us to implement our own locking-mechanism using a boolean value or similar, instead of simply being able to lock the object when it is altered.

If I am not making any sense, do tell. Any answers that might help are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "store data"? Putting data into internal static fields will be wiped out upon application pool restart, so there clearly needs to be a way to reload it. What is the source of the data? API calls? A configuration file?

Comment: @NightOwl888 There will be some initial data given on instantiation (initial hosting) of the Node, and then the state should be altered via calls to its API, i.e. PUT ".../NodeName/executed" true
The data doesn't need to be stored persistently, as it simply lives while the workflow lives. Accessing a database is exactly the opposite of what we want to achieve, as it would place a large load on that database.
We would like some way to refer to a single object of data whenever we handle a call to the Node's API. Does this help a bit?

Comment: So is this data stored between requests? If so, how do you currently tell that it is the same client that is storing/referencing the data from one request to the next?

Comment: @NightOwl888 The idea is that a Node is hosted "somewhere" (anywhere), Nodes know each other through URIs, and some Workflow Process can be asked about which Nodes exist, by a client. This client can then make any call to any Node, and the Node will respond with either 200 or something else, if some condition for execution(or other action) was not fulfilled.
The data should be stored in the Node itself, for as long as it is alive. There is no further requirement to data persistence. When a Node is executed, there are also a number of post-conditions enabling execution of other Nodes

Comment: Why are you not implementing a database? Everything you are describing here is almost textbook uses of a database.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, I would say the persistence mechanism you are after is probably one of the server-side caching options ([`System.Runtime.Caching`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`System.Web.Caching`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

`System.Runtime.Caching` is the newer of the 2 technologies and provides the an abstract [ObjectCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type that could potentially be extended to be file-based. Alternatively, there is a built-in [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type.

Unlike a static method, caches will persist state for all users based on a timeout (either fixed or rolling), and can potentially have cache dependencies that will cause the cache to be immediately invalidated. The general idea is to reload the data from a store (file or database) after the cache expires. The cache protects the store from being hit by every request - the store is only hit after the timeout is reached or the cache is otherwise invalidated.

In addition, you can specify that items are "Not Removable", which will make them survive when an application pool is restarted.

More info: http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/02/caching-in-net-4.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however we have ended up with actually using an object. While unsure of how to receive this upon API initialisation, we figured we could have an API-call which feeds us the object we want, meaning we can then access that object later, upon later API calls. In any case, the issue is resolved. Thanks again.

Comment: could you explain where do you instantiate the object? thanks

Comment: As per the [linked article](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/02/caching-in-net-4.html), you can get an instance of MemoryCache by calling `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default` (provided you are on .NET Framework, not .NET Core).